# How to plot multiple loess curves in a xyplot panel data?

Tags: r, data-visualization, loess

Imagine the following simplified longitudinal data with 4 individuals and 3 variables (y1, y2, y3) measured at 50 occasions :

```
dat<-data.frame(subject=as.factor(rep(1:4, each=50)),time=rep(1:50,4),y1=rnorm(200,50,20),y2=rnorm(200,70,20),y3=rnorm(200,20,20))
```

It is easy to plot at the same time the raw time series with this code :

```
xyplot(y1+y2+y3~time|subject,dat,type='l')
```

which result is :

[image]

I would like to plot exactly the same, but with loess curves instead of lines. And here is my problem!
The following code :

```
xyplot(y1+y2+y3~time|subject,dat,
panel=function(x,y)
    {panel.loess(x,y,span=0.2)
})
```

doesn't work because it considers y1+y2+y3 as a single variable, thus plotting only one loess curve by panel.
How is it possible to plot each loess curve in each panel?

PS. I don't want to use `type="smooth"` because I need to specify the span of the loess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `type='smooth'` instead of `type='l'`:

```
xyplot(y1+y2+y3~time|subject,dat,type='smooth')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as I mentioned in my post, I can't use type="smooth" because I need to specify the span of the loess.
Is it possible to change the parameter of 'smooth'?

Comment: Big ooops!!! It is indeed simple. I didn't know it was possible to change span of smooth.
It works well with this code : `xyplot(y1+y2+y3~time|subject,dat,type='smooth',span=.3)`

My question is perhaps not very useful after all. Perhaps it is better to delete it? Let me know.

Comment: @maxTC Nope. It will probably be useful for future users sharing the same concern.